# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < google-analytics google tag manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I copied the following code right below the body tag for my site. However I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error. When I check in Firebug I get "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" but I am not seeign where the error is. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager --> <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KDKSB8" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src= '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KDKSB8');</script>
 <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I pasted your code into one of my webpages and there was no error.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: Sadly the page is behind a firewall so I can't share the page. You've got me wondering if the error is for something else on the page. I do have the page "working" with the code now, but when I use Chrome, and hit F12 and look at the Network I'm not seeing a gtm.js so it's not running the container. I wonder if it's because it's in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. You may have messed up something else while you were adding this.

Comment: Is anyone using this in SharePoint?

Comment: I've actually had this same error on some of my properties over the last few weeks - the gtm.js script itself will have a syntax error in it for some weird reason, and that will persist for an hour or so, then without changing anything in my tag manager rules or in the way I'm including the gtm.js script, it will go back to normal and start working again. It's happened to  me at least 3 times, and it's starting to get annoying

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well in a php / smarty template environment.  The issue was that { and } are reserved characters with smarty templates and interprets them as indicators of php code.  In case anyone comes across this response and is using smarty, place your code in {literal} and {/literal}.

This may not be your exact situation, but maybe your environment (sharepoint) is interpreting some of the javascript characters as reserved characters.  There might be an escape character to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as Joe says, it's to do with the curly braces that smarty templates use. I got around it by putting the google analytics code into a separate js file and just referenced that js file from the template.